# how to crop image before upload using php?

Tags: php, function, file, post, image-resizing

I was looking for a way to resize a photo before uploading it, I found the code below and it perfectly serves my goal, just want it to don't store the original image alongside the cropped image in the directory. I did some changes to it but didn't work out. I hope I get some help.

```
  if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
      if(is_array($_FILES)) {


    $uploadedFile = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name']; 
    $sourceProperties = getimagesize($uploadedFile);
    $newFileName = time();
    $dirPath = "uploads/";
    $ext = pathinfo($_FILES['file']['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
    $imageType = $sourceProperties[2];


    switch ($imageType) {


        case IMAGETYPE_PNG:
            $imageSrc = imagecreatefrompng($uploadedFile); 
            $tmp = imageResize($imageSrc,$sourceProperties[0],$sourceProperties[1]);
            imagepng($tmp,$dirPath. $newFileName. "_thump.". $ext);
            break;           

        case IMAGETYPE_JPEG:
            $imageSrc = imagecreatefromjpeg($uploadedFile); 
            $tmp = imageResize($imageSrc,$sourceProperties[0],$sourceProperties[1]);
            imagejpeg($tmp,$dirPath. $newFileName. "_thump.". $ext);
            break;

        case IMAGETYPE_GIF:
            $imageSrc = imagecreatefromgif($uploadedFile); 
            $tmp = imageResize($imageSrc,$sourceProperties[0],$sourceProperties[1]);
            imagegif($tmp,$dirPath. $newFileName. "_thump.". $ext);
            break;

        default:
            echo "Invalid Image type.";
            exit;
            break;
    }


    move_uploaded_file($uploadedFile, $dirPath. $newFileName. ".". $ext);
    echo "Image Resize Successfully.";
    }
  }


   function imageResize($imageSrc,$imageWidth,$imageHeight) {

    $newImageWidth =900;
    $newImageHeight =534;

     $newImageLayer=imagecreatetruecolor($newImageWidth,$newImageHeight);



   imagecopyresampled($newImageLayer,$imageSrc,0,0,0,0,$newImageWidth,$newImageHeight,$imageWidth,$imageHeight);

    return $newImageLayer;
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you remove the line `move_uploaded_file` from your code, it won't save the original file (which will remain in the temp folder and eventually get deleted by the system). The rest of your code should work as-is.